# Firefox - Font is changing on :hover

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

Hello there first time here and good a little problem which bothers me.

I am working on a design which looks quite ok at Chrome. But when i change to Firefox the Font is changing  on :hover. For the whole page. Like the font-weight is getting a new value.

I hope somebody can help me fixing this:

http://ggson-test.co.gp/beta/

Thank you very much!

Comment: post your css and html

Comment: I doubt that bx slider is causing that, cuz it happens in nivo as well

Comment: on hovering what? I dont find any change!

Comment: :hover the navigation. It will lighten up the rest of the font in Firefox

Comment: i just took out the bx slider and it is not changing anymore. Will take a better look at this

Answer (score 1):

This is what is causing it :-

```
.nav a:hover:after {   
content: "\25B2";
}
```

Comment: Yes! I took it up and it's gone :) Thanks! Hope to find now a solution to fix that issue. Thanks alot!